# Tracking wheather GPS is Fixed or Not

Tags: android, gps, satellite

I am trying to track weather GPS of android device is Linked to satellites or not. I have already checked many threads, and I can detect when the GPS is first fixed using GpsStatus.Listener interface inplementation. Lets make it simple..

Problem is:
"GPS gets connected (Fixed - Stable icon in the status bar) and disconnected (Scanning - Blinking icon in the status bar) when travelling."

What I want: 
Check weather GPS is connected or not programatically. If GPS is linked, I want my variable "gpsActive" to be "true" and otherwise "false"

What I have done so far:
"Check when the GPS gets fixed first time and set gpsActive to true"

```
    private class GpsStatusListener implements GpsStatus.Listener {

    @Override
    public void onGpsStatusChanged(int event) {

        switch (event) {

            case GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_FIRST_FIX:
                locationListener.onGpsFixed();
                gpsActive = true;

                break;

            case GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_SATELLITE_STATUS:

                int count = 0;
                for (GpsSatellite satellite: locationManager.getGpsStatus(null).getSatellites()) {
                    if (satellite.usedInFix())
                        count++;
                }

                boolean gpsPreActive = gpsActive;

                gpsActive = count >= 4;


                if (gpsPreActive && !gpsActive)
                    locationListener.onGpsUnlinked();

                locationListener.onGpsSatelliteStatus(count);
                break;

            case GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_STARTED:
                locationListener.onGpsStarted();
                break;

            case GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_STOPPED:
                locationListener.onGpsStopped();
                gpsActive = false;
                break;

        }

    }

}
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: In my experience this status "tracking_for-Fix" has no practical usage. What do you need that for? Just look whether fix is valid or not. An invalid fix at ios has horicontalAccurace = -1; android for sure has comparable solution to detect a valid fix.

Comment: Well trying to look for a fix allows me wehather I have to update my location from network or not. If I have a fix, then GPS will update my location. And if I dont have a fix, location will be updated by Network Provider.

"android for sure has comparable solution to detect a valid fix", Is what I'm looking for...

Comment: Why do you need that?  Besides doubtfull indoor navigation, GPS is always more acurate, Just stay at GPS. Othwrise set to GPS_RPOVIDER_ONLY and setup a timer, and if you dont receive a location for some seconds, change to NETWORK provider.